# How can i write a tf?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How can i write a tf?
do anybody have a example of tf?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/120636/how-can-i-write-a-tf?/) by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2014-01-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-01-22**:
What you mean by "write a tf"?

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
I don't know but when i want to creating a map using hector slam, it needs a tf?

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-01-22**:
Is your laser fixed on a robot or are you using laser alone without anything else? It would be nice to make your question more detailed - more details will lead to better answers ;)

**Comment by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) on 2014-01-22**:
Did you check this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot ?

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thanks for your attention dear.
yes, i read tutorial but i don't understand it completely.
my laser fixed on robot by two dynamixel motor (roll and pitch) to Balance it by gyro,
how can i write a tf with this stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ok, with laser scanner fixed on two servos you need following:

- create appropriate [URDF model](http://wiki.ros.org/urdf) (including robot, those servos / joints, your laser scanner)
- publish current angles of servos to `joint_states` topic (`sensor_msgs/JointState`)
- run [robot_state_publisher](http://wiki.ros.org/robot_state_publisher) which will transform joint state to TF
- read carefully tutorial on [how to setup hector_slam](http://wiki.ros.org/hector_slam/Tutorials/SettingUpForYourRobot) on your robot

Then, there will be TF transformation between laser scanner (laser_link in the tutorial) and robot base (base_link).

---

Originally posted by [ZdenekM](https://answers.ros.org/users/1081/zdenekm/) with karma: 704 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [programmer](https://answers.ros.org/users/11096/programmer/) on 2014-01-22**:
Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is plenty of information and tutorials on the [tf page](http://wiki.ros.org/tf).

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2014-01-22

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3